# Tailwind not rendering after installation

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

After I've followed the installation process for Tailwind per their website, I ran npm run dev and the design is still not rendering.

The steps I made:

1: npm install -D tailwindcss

2: npx tailwindcss init

After that, I changed to tailwind.config to:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Along with the my index.css file to be:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

And finally my App.jsx:

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <>
     <h1 className="text-3xl bg-red-500 font-bold underline">
    Hello world!
  </h1>
    </>
  )
}
```

After doing all of this it should be working but the color of bg-red-500 is not showing indicating that tailwind is not working.

Here is an image of how my dir is setup:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `.jsx` files in the Tailwind configuration.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

In addition, install postcss and autoprefixer:

```
npm install -D postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

Comment: i changed it to 

 content: ["./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],

still not working..

Comment: @Cyborgsonny Did you restart the server?

Comment: Yeah, i tried that. No luck yet

Comment: Is it possible that the issue is how my folders are set up? Just thinking out loud

Comment: @Cyborgsonny Did you install postcss and autoprefixer?

Comment: Correct, so I have a folder called currencyConverter in that its the src folder then the app.jsx in that folder

Comment: @Cyborgsonny Install postcss and autoprefixer, then run `npx tailwindcss init -p`.